# LanguageFallback not working

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

So I have a field, where I can change the font color of some text on the hero image inside of Sitecore 8.1. Let's say you can choose between black and white.
Now if I choose a color in the English version of the hero image, it is all working but if I add a german language version and there choose the color for the text, then there it is not working.
I could figure out that this is because there is no german version of the black and white item which has the template `Class Definition`.
So I tried to add the German version for this item and then it worked like expected and desired.

**Next problem**: I don't want to add the German version for all the items and in future do this for all the languages that are coming. Then I figured out that there is something like a language fallback and I tried it.

- In the `Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config` I changed this values to true
  [image]
- Then I set the Fallback Language of the german language item to English
  [image]
- And finally, I checked the Enable Item Fallback in the `standard_values` of the `class definition` item
  [image]
- Now the black and the white versions are looking like this
  [image]

But the color switcher is still not working. What else can I try to make this work?

Comment: I see "English" as fallback language in your screen shot. So is this your custom language because all predefined languages in Sitecore will be having language code. I guess the fallback language field is a drop down and let you choose an existing language. How you have "English" instead of "en", have renamed any predefined language item(s).?

Comment: this is not the raw value...if i activate the raw values then there is "en"

Comment: And yes the language item is renamed. But only the display name not the item name. Is this a problem?

Comment: Is your site name is "website" in Site definition?

Comment: The name of my site was not "website" in the SiteDefinition. The problem is solved now because I changed the "website" to the real name of the site.

Comment: @dave_26456 - please add an answer below with that information so others can benefit from your discovery!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The name of my site was not "website" in the SiteDefinition. The problem is solved now because I changed the "website" to the real name of the site.